# On Users page, location is truncated even though horizontal space is used for tags

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, formatting

The `user-location` span doesn’t use all the available width in the `user-info` div, though the `user-tags` div does, thus:

[image: Screenshot]

CSS bug?

Comment: Dunno about the formatting bug, but I found an interesting, um, anomaly on the user search page: type in `wai`. I guess it returns one result for each match?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, I see the issue.

```
    .user-details
    {
        width: auto;
    }
```

Comment: You’ve tagged this **status-completed**; are you saying it should have been changed? As of today (rev 2011.3.21.2) I don’t see any difference.

Comment: @brian hmm, on my local Chrome adding this worked, but in reality it needs `!important`